# TilePanel like Windows 10 start menu

Tags: wpf, user-interface

Since my initial question was too long, here it shall be as short one: I want to create a TilePanel which acts similiar to Windows 10's start menu just that tiles can be differently sized than small squares, big squares and a rectangle.

My problem lies in the implementation of the reordering and arrangement of the tiles. I tried it by using a [TileMap](https://pastebin.com/x1Bwp8aW)-`class` which maps elements onto a two-dimensional array per "slot" (the minimum size of an element equals one slot, basically a 64x64 square). This again is being used in the arrangement code of the panel where I arrange each container to the given position and size (should work theoretically).

How can I achieve drag & drop with a preview (elements move out of the way) as well as the general arrangement?

Comment: Hello.  Have you defined your own Itemscontrol and related ItemsPanelTemplate?

Comment: Consider Blend fluid behaviors: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn195746(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well yes, I do have a custom `ItemsControl`. So far I only set up the Style for the `ItemContainer` (*Tile*-class). And thanks, that might come in handy with the animation, but that's the least of my worries. The arrangement thing is the thing troubling me most. Especially the "minimalistic movement" - I mean arranging it inititally to fit well is not that hard to realize. But moving tiles around as you put in another one - in the most minimalistic way - that's a bit more difficult.